Calculate percentage of rows containing a string, grouped by month
I would like to calculate the percentage of invoices that contain the word "bend", grouped by month. I have the following sample data in Excel:



Date
Invoice Number
Line Item




08/01/2024
100
Cut material


08/01/2024
100
Cut and bend


09/01/2024
200
Part ABC


09/01/2024
201
Part DEF


10/01/2024
300
Cut and bend


10/01/2024
300
Bend parts


10/03/2024
301
Cut only



The resulting output should be something like:



Month
Percent with bend




08/2024
100%


09/2024
0%


10/2024
50%



I could add a column searching for the word "bend", and then create a PivotTable to get unique Invoice Numbers and whether or not any of their Line Items contain "bend". However, I don't know how to use this to calculate the percent of invoice numbers containing bend grouped by month.

I chose to put the unique months in F2 using a separate formula:
=UNIQUE(DATE(YEAR(A2:A8),MONTH(A2:A8),1))

And the main formula in G2:
=LET(key,E2,month,F2#,date,DATE(YEAR(A2:A8),MONTH(A2:A8),1),invoice,B2:B8,Line,C2:C8,
    MAP(month,LAMBDA(c,IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(invoice,(date=c)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(key,Line))))),0)*100/ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(invoice,date=c))))))


Or if you prefer a single formula:
=LET(key,E2,month,F2#,date,DATE(YEAR(A2:A8),MONTH(A2:A8),1),invoice,B2:B8,Line,C2:C8,
  HSTACK(UNIQUE(date),
    MAP(month,LAMBDA(c,IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(invoice,(date=c)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(key,Line))))),0)*100
      /ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(invoice,date=c)))))))

